# Trouble explaining Haskell code with where and pattern match

Tags: haskell, where-clause

I have hard time parsing how `mf` `m` `y` are assigned values or even why there can be 3 variables on the left side of assignment in `where` section.

**Q: Can anyone explain what happens here in both cases?** (that is for empty list and a list with some elements)

```
-- | A variant of 'foldl' that has no base case,
-- and thus may only be applied to non-empty structures.
--
-- @'foldl1' f = 'List.foldl1' f . 'toList'@
foldl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a
foldl1 f xs = fromMaybe (errorWithoutStackTrace "foldl1: empty structure")
                (foldl mf Nothing xs)
  where
    mf m y = Just (case m of
                     Nothing -> y
                     Just x  -> f x y)
```

(this is the [source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#line-217) for the [`foldl1` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldl1)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have hard time parsing how mf m y are assigned values or even why there can be 3 variables.

You do not define three variables here: you define a variable `mf` which is a function, and `m` and `y` are two *arguments* of the function `mf`.

We can make the function more elegant, and thus omit the `m` and `y`. `mf` can be defined as:

```
mf Nothing = Just . id
mf (Just x) = Just . f x
```

Mind that we can not simply make `mf` an outer function, since it uses a function `f`, with is a parameter of `foldl1`. So we put it in a `where` clause:

```
foldl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a
foldl1 f xs = fromMaybe (errorWithoutStackTrace "foldl1: empty structure")
                (foldl mf Nothing xs)
    where mf Nothing = Just . id
          mf (Just x) = Just . f x
```

Comment: I believe that the original code defines `mf` in that way since it is lazier. (Not sure about the benefit of that, though)

Answer (score 7):

Definitions in `where` clauses follow the same syntax as global definitions, so `mf m y = ...` defines a function named `mf`, which takes parameters named `m` and `y`.

Comment: :/ right, that's just ordinary function definition (somehow I though it's assignment), so `foldl` will first run it with `Nothing` and first element of a list, which will be caught by first branch of case, so first element of list will be returned as future accumulator, after `foldl` runs through a list, `mf` will be returning single value inside `Maybe`, so that's why we need `fromMaybe` which will extract that value, or in case of `Nothing` will execute it's first argument. Thx!

Comment: @przemo_li: Haskell has no *assignments*. It only has *declarations*.

Answer (score 2):

In the empty list case, `foldl mf Nothing [] ~ Nothing` by definition, so `foldl1` will return the `"empty structure"` error.

When `xs` is not empty, then `foldl1'` is simply a left fold by `foldl`. In this case `foldl` has the type

`foldl :: (Maybe a -> a -> Maybe a) -> Maybe a -> [a] -> Maybe a`

which makes use of the combining function `mf :: Maybe a -> a -> Maybe a` defined in the `where` clause.